# Best practice for splitting up Win8 app HTML in multiple files

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I can't seem to find a good solution for splitting up a single page Windows 8 app like one would do with SHTML in the past, or include("test.html"); in PHP.

I have all HTML markup in the default.html. However i want some sections to be moved to its own file. For example move the header from the default.html to a a header.html:

```
// default.html
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.HtmlControl" data-win-options="{uri: 'html/header.html'}"></div>

// html/header.html
<header>
   <h1>App Name</h1>
   <h2><span data-win-res="{textContent: 'subtitle'}"></span></h2>
</header>
```

Note that the textContent is triggered by WinJS.Resources.processAll(); to translate the subtitle. The problem is that the translation does not complete because the header.html is included during runtime.

All in all, I'm either looking for:

a) compile time include method

or b) a way to preload a bunch of html files before i run (like fake a compile include)

```
WinJS.UI.processAll()
WinJS.Resources.processAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

As Michael said, the grid does this, but the Navigation Template does as well and it's much cleaner to look at and understand.
You're looking at using the HtmlControl, but there's another control you can use and it's the PageControl ([WinJS.UI.Pages.PageControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj126158.aspx)). The [HtmlControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700625.aspx) that you are using is a control and it's processed along with all of the other controls and binding, so it sounds like it's processing the data-win-res before it does the html.
I would try:

1. Call the processAll manually on just your HtmlControl div. The [processAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh440975) method can take a root element and even though it's called in the default.js, you can call it yourself before that one happens.
2. Switch to using the PageControl and you have its render method that you can manually call.

Hope one of those two solutions works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The default grid app template does this where the default.html has a frame and all child pages are put into that.